# How to move the Rocket in my first project on pygame Python

Tags: python, pygame

I'll much appreciate it if you help me to resolve the issue with moving Rocket in my project.

I've started to code my first game, based on material that I've learned in the "Python crash course" book.

I need to make Rocket in the game to move all over the window and around its axis.
Everything worked (moving left, right, top, bottom), then I decided to make my Rocket to move around its axis. I spend a lot of time to know how to do it and it already works (left Shift).
But now I faced another problem. My Rocket now doesn't move on the screen, only around its axis. I understand that my question may seem very stupid, and somewhere in my code is obviously a lack of simple logic. But I tried to fix it by myself for several hours and didn't get a result.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys




class Settings():
    """A class to store all settings for Rocket."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game screen settings."""
        # Screen settings.
        self.screen_width = 900
        self.screen_height = 700
        self.bg_color = (21, 36, 110)

class Rocket():
    """A class that describes rocket."""
    def __init__(self, screen):
        """Initialize rocket and its starting position."""
        self.screen = screen
        #Load the rocket image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('/media/philip/9074-45DF/Python/rocket/images/rocket.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        #set starting position of a rocket.
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.centery = self.screen_rect.centery
        #movement flag.
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.rotate_left = False
        self.rocket_angle = 0


    def update(self):
        """Update the rocket position based on the movement flag."""
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.rect.centerx += 2
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.rect.centerx -= 2
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
            self.rect.centery -= 2
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.rect.centery += 2 


    def rotated_center(self, image, rocket_angle):
        """Rotating rocket around its axis."""
        self.center = self.image.get_rect().center
        self.rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.rocket_angle)
        self.new_rect = self.rotated_image.get_rect(center = self.center)
        return self.rotated_image, self.new_rect                       


    def blit_rocket(self, rect, rocket_angle):
        """Draw the rocket at its current location."""       
        if self.rotate_left:
            self.rocket_angle = (self.rocket_angle + 1) % 360 
            self.screen.blit(self.rotated_image, self.new_rect) 
        else:
            self.rocket_angle = (self.rocket_angle + 0) % 360
            self.screen.blit(self.rotated_image, self.new_rect)    
           


    def check_events(self):
        """Respond to a key events."""
        # Responses to the keydown events.
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.moving_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.moving_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.moving_down = True 
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.moving_up = True 
            if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                self.rotate_left = True    

        # Responses to the keyup events.
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.moving_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.moving_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.moving_down = False 
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.moving_up = False  
            if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                self.rotate_left = False        

       



pygame.init()
rocket_settings = Settings()
icon = pygame.image.load('/media/philip/9074-45DF/Python/rocket/images/rocket_icon.png')


pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((rocket_settings.screen_width, rocket_settings.screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rocket")
rocket = Rocket(screen)

"""The main game loop."""
while True:  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()    

    screen.fill((rocket_settings.bg_color))
    rocket.update()
    rocket.check_events()
    rocket.rotated_center(rocket.image, rocket.rocket_angle)
    rocket.blit_rocket(rocket.rect,rocket.rocket_angle)  
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event` has to be an argument of the method `Rocket.check_events`:

```py
class Rocket():
    # [...]

    def check_events(self, event):               # event argument
        """Respond to a key events."""
        # Responses to the keydown events.
        # [...]
```

You have to call `rocket.check_events()` in the event loop and to pass the `event` to the method:

```py
while True:  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        rocket.check_events(event)                          # <--- ADD

    screen.fill((rocket_settings.bg_color))
    rocket.update()                               
    # rocket.check_events()                                   <--- DELETE
    rocket.rotated_center(rocket.image, rocket.rocket_angle)
    rocket.blit_rocket(rocket.rect,rocket.rocket_angle)  
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, but it returns a rectangle that always starts at (0, 0).
You must get the position of the the object from `self.rect.center` rather than `self.image.get_rect().center`:

```py
class Rocket():
    # [...]

    def rotated_center(self, image, rocket_angle):
        """Rotating rocket around its axis."""
        self.rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.rocket_angle)
        self.new_rect = self.rotated_image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        return self.rotated_image, self.new_rect
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
import sys


class Settings():
    """A class to store all settings for Rocket."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game screen settings."""
        # Screen settings.
        self.screen_width = 900
        self.screen_height = 700
        self.bg_color = (21, 36, 110)

class Rocket():
    """A class that describes rocket."""
    def __init__(self, screen):
        """Initialize rocket and its starting position."""
        self.screen = screen
        #Load the rocket image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('/media/philip/9074-45DF/Python/rocket/images/rocket.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        #set starting position of a rocket.
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.centery = self.screen_rect.centery
        #movement flag.
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.rotate_left = False
        self.rocket_angle = 0


    def update(self):
        """Update the rocket position based on the movement flag."""
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.rect.centerx += 2
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.rect.centerx -= 2
        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
            self.rect.centery -= 2
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.rect.centery += 2 


    def rotated_center(self, image, rocket_angle):
        """Rotating rocket around its axis."""
        self.rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.rocket_angle)
        self.new_rect = self.rotated_image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
        return self.rotated_image, self.new_rect                       


    def blit_rocket(self, rect, rocket_angle):
        """Draw the rocket at its current location."""       
        if self.rotate_left:
            self.rocket_angle = (self.rocket_angle + 1) % 360 
            self.screen.blit(self.rotated_image, self.new_rect) 
        else:
            self.rocket_angle = (self.rocket_angle + 0) % 360
            self.screen.blit(self.rotated_image, self.new_rect)    
           


    def check_events(self, event):
        """Respond to a key events."""
        # Responses to the keydown events.
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.moving_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.moving_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.moving_down = True 
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.moving_up = True 
            if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                self.rotate_left = True    

        # Responses to the keyup events.
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.moving_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.moving_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.moving_down = False 
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.moving_up = False  
            if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                self.rotate_left = False        

       



pygame.init()
rocket_settings = Settings()
icon = pygame.image.load('/media/philip/9074-45DF/Python/rocket/images/rocket_icon.png')


pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((rocket_settings.screen_width, rocket_settings.screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Rocket")
rocket = Rocket(screen)

"""The main game loop."""
while True:  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()    

        rocket.check_events(event)

    screen.fill((rocket_settings.bg_color))
    rocket.update()
    rocket.rotated_center(rocket.image, rocket.rocket_angle)
    rocket.blit_rocket(rocket.rect,rocket.rocket_angle)  
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: @Rabbit76 OMG, thank you! It's my first question on Stackoverflow. I didn't expect to get an answer so quickly. Blessings to you.